# Custom welcome message and invitation system Discord bot

Tags: discord.py

when a person is joining the server, then the bot sends a message to the chat "Person1 was invited by user 2. Person2 has x invitees." I tried to write like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if welcome_channel := member.guild.get_channel(881620025948135436#id):
        await welcome_channel.send(f"`` {member.name}``logged into the server by invitation `` {member.name}``")
    await  member.send(embed=discord.Embed(
```

but it turns out that Person1 entered the server at the invitation of Person1.

Comment: There is a bot similar to what you need: https://top.gg/bot/690444162201288714

Or maybe look at this and try to understand its code: https://github.com/aloshai/invite-manager

Answer (score 1):

The `on_member_join()` event itself gives no information about who invited who, the only way to know who invited who is to save a version of the guild's invites  which you can get with `await guild.invites` and compare that saved version with the version after the new member joined. There will be one invite in the list that has 1 more `invite.uses` than before, the `invite.inviter` is the user who invited the member that just joined.

Some example code.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   if welcome_channel := member.guild.get_channel(881620025948135436): #I dont quite know how the walrus operator works, I assume it does work and just copied your code (I guess it skips if the guild the member joined doesnt have the channel and returns None on the get_channel)
      new_invites = await member.guild.invites()
      for i in range(len(new_invites)):
         if new_invites[i].uses != old_invites[i].uses:
            inviter = new_invites[i].inviter
            uses = new_invites[i].uses
      await welcome_channel.send(f"{member} joined the server with {inviter}'s invite, they have invited {uses} members")
      old_invites = new_invites
```

This is only the code for the join event itself, it wont work by itself, you still need to:

- Load the `old_invites` in the `on_ready()` event
- Update the `old_invites` whenever it gets updated (things like invite creation/deletion, anything that can change the invite list)
- If you want to do that: keep track of people leaving for your leaderboard of invitees (you'll have to keep track of who invited them for every single user in the guild)

Comment: Write all the code straight. otherwise I have errors. I can’t remove them

Comment: I dont quite get what you mean with that sentence?

Comment: help me i have errors


line 71, in on_member_join
    new_invites = await guild.invites
NameError: name 'guild' is not defined

Comment: Ah yes, that should indeed be member.guild.invites, ill update my code accordingly

Comment: line 73, in on_member_join
    new_invites = await member.guild.invites
TypeError: object method can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: you can write all the code so that there are no errors?

Comment: I found the mistake: `guild.invites` needed some extra () after it.(as it is a function) Nobody can guarantee that their code has no errors, im trying my best but i cant test the code rn....

Comment: Thanks. I have the last error left line 74, in on_member_join
     if new_invites [i] .uses! = old_invites [i] .uses:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'old_invites' referenced before assignment

Comment: That is caused by the fact that you need to make old_invites a variable before using it, it is one of the things i didnt code for you, the loading of the invites in on_ready() (as global variable)

Comment: So async def on_ready (old_invites): or so async def old_invites () :?

Comment: what you need is to change the on_ready() command, it is a command that is run after the bot finishes initialising (loading everything), so what you want to do is `@bot.event; async def on_ready():` (change ; for an newline) and write your code (to save the old invitelist[on how to do that, you can look at how i got the invites in my piece of code and use that, also make old_invites a global variable]) there. That way it'll load the invites when the bot starts

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you, though I'll gladly help with any errors you encounter while writing it